# Generate system.xml default value

Tags: system.xml, default

I'm creating an extension that exposes an API to another web site. My extension will create an API key, and then you'll copy this API key into the other web site, which will let Magento and the other site exchange data.

I've created a `system.xml` entry for my API key. I'd like for the default value for this config item to be populated by a call to a `generateApiKey` method defined in PHP code.

In pseudocode, `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <default>
       <my_extension>
            <api_connection>
                <apikey><?php echo $obj->generateApiKey(); ?></apikey>
            </api_connection>
        </my_extension>
    </default>
</config>
```

I know that that's not possible, but hopefully that conveys what I want to do.

How can I programmatically generate (and save) a default value for something defined in `system.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest populating the value via a data migration script. Create a resource in your module's `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_namespace_my_extension>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </my_namespace_my_extension>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <my_namespace_my_extension>
                <setup>
                    <module>MyNamespace_MyModule</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </my_namespace_my_extension>
        </resources>
    </global>
```

Create a the migration script: `MyNamespace/MyExtension/data/my_namespace_my_extension/data-install-1.0.0.php`

```
/* @var $this Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$generatedKey = Mage::helper('my_extension')->generateApiKey();
$this->setConfigData('my_extension/api_connection/apikey', $generatedKey);
```

NOTE: the cache would most likely need to be cleared after installation. This should be made clear in your module's installation instructions. It should also be possible to flag the cache as invalidated.

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->invalidateType('config');
```

Comment: Is that going to work? The `setConfigData` method will set the node value, but it won't persist the value to a database anywhere.

Comment: It should, checkout the source [here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L892). Are you referring to `Mage::getConfig()->setNode()` perhaps?

Comment: Should this install script have the usual $installer->startSetup() and $installer->endSetup() calls?

Comment: It's not necessary, the "data" scripts are meant for populating data. The start/end setup methods concern themselves with how the database behaves (e.g. turning off foreign key constraints).

Answer (score 2):

You can just save it into `core_config_data`.

So either in `$setup->setConfigData($path, $value)` or `Mage::app()->getConfig()->saveConfig($path, $value)` but be careful, the second one doesn't clean the cache.